# Does the Facebook Graph API allow to search by e-mail?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I'm trying to search by e-mail using the Facebook Graph API but I always got the error result:

request: **.../search?q=some@email.coml&type=user**
result:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

I´m using an access token and this one is a user's (mine) valid access token. **If I do a search for any thing else (like a name) it works fine.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can only search by name, but not by email:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search